# HTC Softkeyboard key that hidden the keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, htc-android

On the HTC keyboard there is an additional key that allows the 
keyboard to be hidden.  When this key is pressed the keyboard is 
hidden but no KeyEvent.

How to get this event or callback method maybe??
I can't use this method  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
because my app is in landscape mode, so it show full screen softkeyboard and doesn't resize the activity.
But i need to know the event when my softkeyboard no longer visible.
Thanks

Comment: yes ,i am facing same problem in HTC Incredible S ,it have one button in Soft Keyboard  which make is hide .If you have find any solution then let me known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is impossible. There is no callback when the keyboard opens or closes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `BaseinputConnection` you can override `finishComposingText()`. That methode will be called when you finish inputting text or when hiding soft keyboard.